# Accessing class data in static setter in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am trying to achieve the following: Store data from subclasses in the superclass.

The following example does works in practice but I have been told that the use of `static get|set x() {}` in the example below is not correct since the `setter` method uses `this._data` which is out of the context of the immediate function, i.e. not passed into the function as an argument, and as such the setter is no longer static.

**Example:**

```
'use strict';

// base.js
class Base {
    constructor () {}

    static get data () {
        return this._data;
    }

    static set data (newData) {
        // merge newData into existing data
        return this._data = _.assign({}, this._data, newData);
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// a.js
class A extends Base {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    add (obj) {
        Base.data = obj;
    }
}
let a = new A();
a.add({b: 'test'});
// -> Expectation: Base.data = { b: 'test' } now

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// b.js
class B extends Base {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    add (str) {
        Base.data = {
            someFixedKey: str
        };
    }
}
let b = new B();
b.add('hello');
// -> Expectation: Base.data = { b: 'test', someFixedKey: 'hello' } now
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to have a single superclass that sits at the base of multiple other subclasses and these subclasses can store their data in the superclass which then does PubSub notifications whenever the data changes and is able to send a full data object containing all data stored by all subclasses with that PubSub event.

If the setter/getter in my `base.js` are not `static`, the issue I was having is that `a.js` will only track `a.js`'s data and not know about `b.js`'s data.

If this is indeed an invalid use case of static getter/setter accessors, I may have to split out the data store ability into a separate singleton that tracks the data and is a dependency for all subclasses. Not the end of the world, but since this "works" I would like to learn more about the use case for static getters and setters.

Thanks for taking a look.

---

**Update:** Here is the example as a JS Fiddle which also demonstrates (in a reduced test case how it *should* work:

- "Working" example using `static`: https://jsbin.com/koruba/2/edit?js,console
- "Non working" example not using `static`: https://jsbin.com/koruba/3/edit?js,console

The question is: Regardless of whether a singleton/pubsub store would be better, is the use of `static` within the `Filters` superclass valid? Especially the `static set data (newData) {}` method since it actually accesses `this._data` and I have been told that for any method to be `static` I must not access anything outside that immediate function and since `this._data` is not passed into the method as an argument I should not use `static` here.

Comment: So... what's the question? It works as expected, doesn't it? And it should. This statement *the setter method uses this._data which is out of the context of the immediate function* is wrong. `this` for `Base.data...` is `Base`. But it won't work as expected if you will use `Base.data` in one place and `B.data` in another. But it works again if you keep the reference to prototype's `data` with `Object.assign(this._data, newData)` instead of reassigning it every time. And it can be referred in children as `this.constructor.data`.

Comment: Any way, the whole thing looks rather clumsy, a singleton storage sounds like a better design option.

Comment: "*the issue I was having is that a.js will only track a.js's data and not know about b.js's data.*" - Can you show your actual code, especially how you are requiring all the modules and logging `Base.data`?

Comment: Yes, a separate singleton would be a better idea than convoluting it with the Base class. And even better than a singleton would be to pass a PubSub store as a dynamic parameter.

Comment: @estus, @Bergi: I've updated the question with clarifications and examples including the way it "works" and the way it "doesn't work" when not using `static` set/get methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Non working" example not using `static`

Yes, by not using `static` your properties will be set on each instance separately, so they aren't shared by anything.

> I have been told that for any method to be `static` I must not access anything outside that immediate function and since `this._data` is not passed into the method as an argument I should not use `static` here.

Whoever told you that probably referred to instance properties. If you call a static method from an instance method, you cannot access the instance's properties using `this` of course, that's the whole point of static methods.
However, like in every other method call you can access properties of the object you are called upon, which for a static method is the class (constructor function) itself. Using `this._data` does access the *static* `Base._data` property - and that is what you want in your use case, so it's totally fine to use it.

Comment: Thanks, so the notion that a `static` method is only static "If it only works on arguments provided to it." is not entirely correct? I'm just trying to figure out if I am violating that rule by accessing `this._data` or as you've explained `Base._data` effectively though it was not passed into the `static set data (newData) {}` method here. As I understand this "rule" the method should've been defined as `set data (newData, baseData) {}` to be truly static but that seems odd given that the `Base._data` is the target of the operation in effect.

Comment: @Jannis No, "works only on arguments provided to it" would be a [pure method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). "static" means essentially "not instance-specific". Although static methods with side-effects are considered bad practise, for the same reason as singletons are.

Comment: Ah nice, now it all makes sense, and the fact that this method is not changing the state of anything other than its `Base._data` target (and accessing it in its method) means it's not considered a side-effect right?

Comment: But of course, `Base._data` is a global "variable" and mutating it is a side-effect. `Base` is effectively a singleton object in that regard.

Comment: Nice, now I get it: the static get/set in my example were valid in that they were non instance specific but were also bad practice because I am mutating state in a variable outside the setter method itself. Thanks again.